# Equivalent definition of boundedness in topological vector space involving sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $B \subseteq X$. I need to show that the following definitions are equivalent:

$(i)$ $B$ is bounded, that is for every neighbourhood $U $of $0$ there exists a $\lambda_U>0$ such that $B \subseteq \lambda_U U$

$(ii)$ For every neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ there exists a $\mu_U>0$ such that $B \subseteq \lambda U$ for every $\lambda >\mu_U$

$(iii)$ For every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of elements of $B$ and every sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of complex numbers with $\lim_{n \to \infty}\alpha_n=0$ we have: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\alpha_nx_n=0$

I already showed that $(i)\Leftrightarrow(ii)$. How can I show that these are equivalent to $(iii)$

Comment: If (i) des not hold, there is a 0-neighbourhood $U $ with $B $ not contained in $n^2U $...

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about this? Why are these statements the same? How do they express boundedness? Once you have understood the statements proving they are the same is just a matter of unpacking definitions.